# Warehouse Management UX : Managing Warehouse Entities in Single Window Interface

Tags: hierarchy, inventory

Warehouse Management UX : Managing Warehouse Entities in Single Window Interface.

I am designing UI/UX for a warehouse management system.
As a warehouse consist of a hierarchy of containers as mentioned below.
Warehouse building -> Zone -> Aisle -> Bay ->  Rack -> Shelve -> Bin

Other moveable containers (tote, cart, palette, Box)

I am looking  forward to designing a single window interface
from which users can add / update and delete all hierarchical warehouse entities.

This application will be used by 3PL company staff who manages the warehouse.

In my current approach I have categorized warehouse entities into below mentioned categories.

1. Layout  (Zone, Aisle, Bay)
2. Storage Unit (Rack, Shelf, Bin)
3. Movable (Tote, palette, cart, Bin)

I have placed a dropdown at the top of the screen which will contain all of the above categories.
When a user selects any category, all the elements inside that category will be displayed in tabs besides the category selection dropdown.

Once the user selects a tab. A table will be displayed with the properties of the selected entity.
Wire frame example of the zone entity is attached below.

I have added textbox under each property heading so that user can enter a value and filter the records being displayed in the table.

[image]

Once a user clicks add entity instance or attempts to edit a existing entity instance available in the table. A pop up will be display to add and edit all the properties of the selected entity.
Below is the example of the pop-up.

[image]

I have Below doubts about my approach.

1. Is this approach feasible for large amount of instances created for each entity considering its a warehouse management system?
2. Is this the best way, to manage entities in hierarchy for a warehouse/inventory management ?
3. Is this UI representation best for standard sized screen at warehouse terminals ?
4. In the future we might display the inventory which will be present inside these respective warehouse
   entity in the same instance property table. Will this be a feasible approach for warehouse entity and its inventory management ?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If you can do some interviews with warehouse managers ( ideally who have used a similar physical set up) you may get some very useful information.

How people use a system isn't necessarily how it might seem logically.